# How can I compare current time with two given time ranges in a text box. C#

Tags: c#, datetime, date-comparison

I have two text boxes that contains the time range a of doctor like 20:00 to 04:00. I want to compare these time ranges with the current time to tell if the doctor is available or not.

[image: GUI Image]

Notice the Doctor Timings From 20 00 To 06 00 and the Current time 21:01:54.
It is in the range so I'll just print "Available" in Doctor Status.

I have stored the doctor's timing in string in "Doctor's Info" using 4 combo boxes and adding the 24 Hour time in collections.
Is there a way to make it work or I'll have to redo the timings in DateTime format? If yes then please help with an example code.
Thank you.

Comment: I think this is definitely doable, can you please share the code and we can work out a solution

Comment: DateTime type would make the comparison trivial by using < and >

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below code to compare if the the current time falls between the specified timing in the application.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Today;
DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day, 6, 0, 0);
DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day, 20, 0, 0);
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now > dt1 && DateTime.Now<dt2);
```